# Background color not changing in div despite setting it

Tags: html, css, background-color

I feel like I'm going crazy, this is simple stuff yet it just refuses to work, I've done it a million times (although it's been awhile.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        title {
            background-color: #000000;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            overflow:auto;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="title">
            <p>
                <img src="images/new/Salon.jpg" width="530" height="180" style="" border="0" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The background color is not changing and that is literally all I've coded so far

Comment: you are missing a dot... (.title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```
title {
```

instead of

```
.title {
```

Comment: Thanks, its been awhile and I have a bit of a headache, still doesn't want to work for some reason. Edit: Nevermind, got it, Thank you!

Comment: It does work here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyqwoL - I only put the dot in front of `title`, otherwise I copied your code 1:1